# mongo.so working fine with php apache ini but not with php cli

Tags: apache-httpd, php5, mongodb

I added the `mongo.so` extension to `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and it is loading perfectly in php info.

But it does not work with `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`.

When I try to run composer for adding mongodb lib it gives this error:

```
mongodb/mongodb 1.0.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
```

Do anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

mongo.so is the legacy driver but you need the new one https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb and it should be installed like described here http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-driver/#installation

You need at least these packages for building `php5 php-pear php5-dev openssl pkg-config libpcre3-dev`